# Python Scrapy Request method not working

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to use the `Request` method of `Scrapy` below but it is not calling the `callback` `self.link_to_problem`. The url's all printing correctly when I call `print path` and I also tried opening those URL's in my browser and the format is correct. Can someone identify if there is something wrong in the code?

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.request import Request
import scrapy

def parse_item(self, response):
    for link in response.xpath("//div[@id='siteTable']//div[@class='entry unvoted']/p[@class='title']/a/@href").extract():
        path = "https://www.reddit.com" + str(link)
        print path
        yield Request(path, callback=self.link_to_problem, errback = self.error_print)

def link_to_problem(self, response):
        print response
        print "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: is `link_to_problem` called? did you check that? also be extar cautious when asking question.

Comment: No `link_to_problem` is not being called which I why I think there might be something wrong with how I am calling the Request method.

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code please review the project settings and code carefully. Or else try removing errback.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your scraper won't work even if the posted code is correct (and at a first glance it seems so to me).

**Reason/Problem: reddit.com blocks requests of all clients that have no User-Agent header set that looks like a real browser.**

Scrapy by default sends 'scrapybot' as user agent and will be blocked because of this.

**Solution:** set a User-Agent header in your requests like a real browser would do.

This can be done by adding the following line to your scrapy project's settings.py file.

`USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'`